# How to Add Service Reference when WCF lives in a console host app?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf

I want to self-host a WCF service in a console application for debugging that lives in my hosting layer.  I also have a WPF application that needs to call this WCF service.  However, I am unable to Add Service Reference to the console project from the WPF project.  What do I do in this scenario?  This is easy to do with IIS self-host, just add a .svc file and have it point to the WCF service, but how to do this with console host?

Comment: What does the relevant bit of your config look like? In which project does the service contract live? Remember, you can also [generate a client using svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx) if the add reference doesn't behave.

Comment: Oh, maybe I will have to use that tool.  You should add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run the console app and ensure that the service is running.
Then go to AddServiceReference in visual studio and follow your intuition

Answer (score 1):

One alternative to using "add service reference" is to [generate a client using SvcUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx). Just fire up the service hosted in your console app, and execute a command in the Visual Studio command prompt with a signature somehwat like this (all on *one* command line):

```
svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:generatedProxy.cs /config:app.config 
http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service
```

The final bit is the actual address of your service, and may differ based on your host.